# Help identifying a varistor?

Tags: identification, varistor

Need help identifying a component that I think is a varistor.  It is burnt so it appears black.  The circuit is part of a control module for the headlights and keyless entry on a Lincoln.  I want to replace the part but can't seem to identify it's value so I can match it up.  [image][image][image]

Comment: It could also be a thermistor. Can you decode an small diagram on how it is placed on the board? Is it in parallel with an AC source or in series?

Comment: Please add photos of both sides of this part of the board.

Comment: It doesn't look burnt from this angle - seems 'naturally' black.

Comment: It got hot enough to melt the plastic case of the module, and burn the trace on back of the circuit board

Comment: Are there any year marks on the PCB? How about some dimensions of the part?

Comment: PCB is from 1994. As for dimensions it is 15mm diameter or almost 5/8 inch.

Comment: [About a third down this page might be what you need to know](https://www.feoa.net/threads/second-engine-typical-auto-transmission-behavior.83128/page-2)

Answer (score 5):

The color is too even for it to be a result of getting burned.  It looks to me like that's its natural gray color.

It could be a MOV (metal oxide varistor), but other component types are possible too.  The lead going diagonally across the face makes MOV the most likely.

The bottom line of text indicates it was made by TDK.  Look around at likely parts on their web site.  If that doesn't work after a reasonable effort, email a picture of the part to their tech support.  They should be able to identify it.

### Added

Now that you've shown a picture of the board, we can see that the part designator is MOV1.  That removes any doubt about it being a MOV.

Comment: Yes, I just need a size for replacement.   Numbers do not match anything on TDK site and had no reply at all from customer service.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a MOV. They typically fail short, so probably this blew a fuse if the overheated traces on the PCB are still intact (check them and bypass them if they are damaged).

If you can't find a part number, you can generally replace it fairly safely with one of the same approximate diameter and voltage rating.

But we don't need to do that, because @Andyaka (see comments) has found an apparent TDK/EPCOS substitute B72210S1140K102 which is 13mm diameter and plausibly rated for a 12V automotive environment.

[Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/epcos-tdk/B72210S1140K102/495-2054-ND/651469) probably has enough in stock (13,359) to cover your immediate needs, at a very reasonable price.

Comment: TDK calls these SIOVs.  See their Cautions and Warnings.

Comment: @MarkFarrow Andy found the number, and Olin got you to post more photos. I just snuck in and added a bit of general info.